# Passing value from one component to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a query.. I need to pass the value from one component to other component.. I want the value received (view console) after click event in the breedlist.js component to replace the base url value "akita" value in the breedimages.js
Refer to:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kfwzgi

Comment: The way I usually do this is to pass up a value to a common ancestor (in your case their parent), and set the value there in the state. The second component then needs to take that state as property.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you will need to define additional props on both < `<BreedImages />` and `<BreedList />` components to handle the receiving of selected breeds, and selecting/clicking of breeds, respectively.

On your index.js,

```
const BASE_URL= "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all"
class App extends Component {
   state={
    breeds: [],
    selectedBreed: undefined,
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch(BASE_URL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        breeds: Object.keys(data.message)
        })
    })
  }

  handleSelect(selectedBreed) {
    this.setState({ selectedBreed });
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedBreed } = this.state;

    return (
      <Router>
       <div className="App">
       <Route path="/" exact strict render={
         ()=> {
           return (<BreedList handleSelect={(val) => this.handleSelect(val)}/>)
         }
       }/>
       <Route path="/images/" exact strict render={
         ()=> {
           return (<BreedImages breed={selectedBreed}/>)
         }
       }/>

      </div>
       </Router>

    );
  }
}
```

Then, on your BreedList.js, you will need to modify the `clickHandler` method such that it is calling the `handleSelect` props method, to pass the selected dog breed back to the parent `index.js` component,

```
clickHandler(e) {
  const val = e.currentTarget.value
  this.props.handleSelect(val)
}
```

Then, on your BreedImages.js, you can listen to the prop updates on the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook, and carry out the necessary operations from there.

I added an `if` statement to compare the prop values before doing any additional operations, as this will prevent any unnecessary re-rendering or requests.

```
componentDidUpdate(props, prevProps){
  if (props.breed !== prevProps.breed) {
    console.log(props);
    // handle the rest
  }
}
```

I have forked your demo and made the changes over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-59ts5g?file=components%2FBreedList.js).